# How to do dependency parsing in R language?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I did POSTagging. But how to do dependency parsing? Can I get the code for it in R language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you already figured out. if not, how I did dependency parsing in R:

```
library(cleanNLP)
library(udpipe)

s <- "I prefer the morning flight through Denver"

cnlp_init_udpipe()
doc <- cnlp_annotate(s, as_strings = TRUE)
cnlp_get_dependency(doc, get_token = FALSE)
```